# Dynamically instantiate Rails nested STI subclass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, types, sti

Let's say I have a class like:

```
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fruits
```

Where "fruits" is an STI base class having subclasses like "apples", "oranges", etc...

I'd like to be able to have a setter method in Basket like:

```
def fruits=(params)
  unless params.nil?
    params.each_pair do |fruit_type, fruit_data|
      fruit_type.build(fruit_data)
    end
  end
end
```

But, obviously, I get an exception like:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `build' for "apples":String)
```

A workaround I thought of works like this:

```
def fruits=(params)
  unless params.nil?
    params.each_pair do |fruit_type, fruit_data|
      "#{fruit_type}".create(fruit_data.merge({:basket_id => self.id}))
    end
  end
end
```

But that causes the Fruit STI object to be instantiated before the Basket class, and so the basket_id key is never saved in the Fruit subclass (because basket_id doesn't exist yet).

I'm totally stumped.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a setter method in Basket, add it in Fruit:

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  def type_setter=(type_name)
    self[:type]=type_name
  end
end
```

Now you can pass the type in when you build the object through an association:

```
b = Basket.new
b.fruits.build(:type_setter=>"Apple")
```

Note that you can't assign `:type` this way, since it is protected from mass assignment.

**EDIT**

Oh, you wanted to run different callbacks depending on the subclass? Right.

You could do this:

```
fruit_type = "apples"
b = Basket.new
new_fruit = b.fruits << fruit_type.titleize.singularize.constantize.new
new_fruit.class # Apple
```

or define a `has_many` association for each type:

```
require_dependency 'fruit' # assuming Apple is defined in app/models/fruit.rb

class Basket
  has_many :apples
end
```

then

```
fruit_type = "apples"
b = Basket.new
new_fruit = b.send(fruit_type).build
new_fruit.class # Apple
```

Comment: This works for my purposes.  But if I understand this correctly, this means that any callbacks I might have on my STI subclasses won't run, correct?

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby terms, `"#{x}"` is simply equivalent to `x.to_s` which for String values is exactly the same as the string itself. In other languages, like PHP, you can de-reference a string and treat it as a class, but that's not the case here. What you probably mean is this:

```
fruit_class = fruit_type.titleize.singularize.constantize
fruit_class.create(...)
```

The `constantize` method converts from a string to the equivalent class, but it is case sensitive.

Keep in mind that you're exposing yourself to the possibility someone might create something with `fruit_type` set to `"users"` and then go ahead and make an administrator account. What's perhaps more responsible is to do an additional check that what you're making is actually of the right class.

```
fruit_class = fruit_type.titleize.singularize.constantize
if (fruit_class.superclass == Fruit)
  fruit_class.create(...)
else
  render(:text => "What you're doing is fruitless.")
end
```

One thing to watch out for when loading classes this way is that `constantize` will not auto-load classes like having them spelled out in your application does. In development mode you may be unable to create subclasses that have not been explicitly referenced. You can avoid this by using a mapping table which solves the potential security problem and pre-loading all at once:

```
fruit_class = Fruit::SUBCLASS_FOR[fruit_type]
```

You can define this constant like this:

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  SUBCLASS_FOR = {
    'apples' => Apple,
    'bananas' => Banana,
    # ...
    'zuchini' => Zuchini
  }
end
```

Using the literal class constant in your model will have the effect of loading them immediately.

Comment: OK, that's a good idea, but I'm still stuck.  Basket does not appear to be looking for a class, because we're creating some kind of Fruit through the Basket has_many :fruits association.  So this works: Basket.fruits.create(params) or Basket.apples.create(params) but not Basket.fruit_class.create(params).

Comment: You wouldn't create this through the association since the association itself is typed. What you can do is create the child object with the `basket` property merged in, like you have in your question.

Comment: But you can't do that, because Basket.id is not known yet-- Basket hasn't yet been saved.